# Usage of subprocess.Popen with CVS repository?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, cvs

I'm writing a python script to add some functionality to a CVS repository.  I'm trying to use the subprocess.Popen module to run a cvs checkout through the windows command line, e.g.

```
subprocess.Popen('cvs -Q co -r %tag% %directory%')
```

where tag and directory are just placeholders (the script takes user input for them).  I have CVSROOT set, but for whatever reason I can't get the script to checkout the desired cvs module.  Running that same command (within the quotes) directly in the command line works as expected, checking out the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are not passed to subprocess.Popen as a string. You need to pass the command and arguments in a list

```
subprocess.Popen(['cvs', '-Q', 'co', '-r', '%tag%', '%directory%'])
```

or alternatively

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('cvs -Q co -r %tag% %directory%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want the same behaviour as in the shell, you should say so:

```
subprocess.Popen('cvs -Q co -r %tag% %directory%', shell=True)
```

But generally it is better to do

```
subprocess.Popen(['cvs', '-Q', 'co', '-r', tag, directory])
```

instead.

Comment: The second approach protects you from problems if, for instance, the directory name has spaces in it (or worse, characters like > ; |). On windows the Popen implementation will quote these things; on linux the shell is bypassed so it's not an issue.

Comment: I've tried both, and still no dice.  The first method setting shell=True just returned <subprocess.Popen object at 0x00...> and didn't open a command prompt.  The second method listing the commands as strings briefly brought up a command prompt, but it closed immediately and I couldn't read the text (i.e. if there was an error message) and it didn't checkout the module.  This is the same outcome as what I had tried earlier.

Comment: Can you open cmd.exe and type in the command there, and have it work?

Comment: @greggo Yes, the command works when I run it directly in the cmd prompt.  The module gets checked out.

Comment: Try also adding the options stdout = logfile, stderr = logfile, where 'logfile' is a file you've open for writing. Something useful may appear in that file.

Comment: Try using subprocess.call with the same options? Popen doesn't wait for the operation to finish, and when you don't catch the return value, the subprocess object is destroyed. Maybe that's killing it.

Comment: I'll try subprocess.call in a moment.  I followed your suggestion  to add the stdout and stderr options.  The logfile I created indicated that CVS didn't like the tag I called, despite it working directly from the command line.

Comment: subprocess.call returns '1' and the logfile indicates the same error, which doesn't seem to make sense since it is working if I just input the command into cmd.exe.

Comment: Do you have the proper environment in the Popen? SVNROOT, current dir, PATH?